# Associations are not mapping properly in Spring boot and JPA Entities Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I've recently got a problem with mapping Entities with JPA. Got a class Client:

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Client")
    public class Client {@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Adress")
    private String adress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Email> emails;
}
```

and class Email:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Email")
public class Email {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Adress")
    private String adress;

    @ManyToOne
    private Client client;

}
```

In the controller I'm adding connection between them:

```
public Client addClient(@RequestBody Client client) {
    client.setId(0);
    List<Email> emails = client.getEmails();
    Client savedClient = service.save(client);
    client.setEmails(null);
    emails.forEach(email -> email.setClient(savedClient));
    return savedClient;
}
```

but the constraints in the database (MySQL) are not created.

I've tried every possible mapping, but cannot resolve this issue. Has anyone any idea what could be the reason of this behaviour? Is it a problem with wrong mapping or database configuration?

Thanks in advance`

Comment: Why are you setting emails to null?

Comment: You're right, that was my mistake - I used manually adding association instead of using JPA Repository. Unfortunately, even when I've changed controller like this
``` @PostMapping("/")
    public Client addClient(@RequestBody Client client) {
        client.setId(0);
        return service.save(client);
    } ```
the connection between entities is not created.

Comment: You need to set the client for each e-mail *before* you save: `client.getEmails().forEach(email -> email.setClient(client));`

Comment: Ok, I see, but I wonder - shouldn't JPA do all the job around creatting assosiacion between entities, without the need to do it manually in controller?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @WiliE.Coyote92 the `Client` you are receiving is obtained by parsing the JSON in the request's body. The JSON parser doesn't know how to handle the JPA mapping; so `emails` is just a list of e-mail addresses. You can't specify the `client` attribute in the JSON because it's the very object that is being parsed.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. So I need to create Deserializer of JSON and add it to the controller, am I right?

Thanks a lot